# “Hg Rollback” would recover deleted files (removed via ‘hg remove’)?

Tags: mercurial, rollback

I removed file “foo.cpp” using mercurial ‘hg remove foo.cpp’ from my repository and commit changes (say the revision of changeset is “22”), then I rollback the change by “hg rollback” and mercurial reported success “Repository tip rolled back to revision 21 (undo commit)”.

Does ‘hg rollback’ recover deleted files from the change-set being rolled back? Seems like it does not recover removed files, is this by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rollback reverts the commit, not the remove.  If you `hg status`, you will see the uncommitted removal of `foo.cpp`.  If you do a clean update to the parent via `hg update -C`, `foo.cpp` will be restored.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I tried "hg revert foo.cpp" (after hg rollbak) which restored the file foo.cpp.